# Amazon MWS - getOrders

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to get orders with Amazon MWS, but ran into some problems. Yes, I have tested this with their MSW scratchpad, and got results. But now I tried to enter their "String to sign" in my browser  get this:

**Parameter Signature cannot be empty.**

So I go and use Amazons [code](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html#DG_OwnClientLibrary__Signatures) to calculate a signature and generete my own "String to sign" and this is what I get, my credentials are all good, copied from scratchpad. If it works there it must work here? Nope.

I only changed this piece of code:

```
parameters.put("Action", urlEncode("GetOrder")); // GetServiceStatus
```

And added AmazonOrderId.id.1

```
parameters.put("AmazonOrderId.Id.1", urlEncode("xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"));
```

**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

I also have their library and can't figure out how to use to get me getOrders, it only has getServiceStatus sample, can't seem to find any class that has function getOrders.

Please help.

Comment: Or should I aproach this problem from antoher angel?

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was, I wass using wrong library, instead of orders library I was using sellers library.

Now I got the request as in scratchpad.